# Get the datas in render but when displaying it, nothings appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing a big problem in react native.
I have a react-native-maps and some markers on it.
And i want that when you click on the marker, you get some datas and i display it in the marker.
But i was able to get the datas but when i display it nothing shows. However in the render function when i do a console.log i cans see that my display, so i can't understand why the data is present in the render and not in the return, that make no sense to me, i tried everything...

Here is my code.
If someone could help me, it would be very nice.
Thanks you :)

I just put a random free api to show you

```
export class CustomMarker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bonjour: ""
    }
  }

  getData() {
    axios.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then((data) => {
      this.setState({ bonjour: data.data.message})
      //console.log(this.state.bonjour)
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.bonjour)
    return (

      <Marker key={this.props.id} coordinate = {{latitude: Number(this.props.data.dLocLati), longitude: Number(this.props.data.dLocLongi)}}
          pinColor = {"red"}
          title={this.props.data.iVehId}
          description={this.props.data.sLocStatus}
          onPress={() => this.getData()
          }
          >
      <Callout>
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.bonjour}</Text>
      </View>
        </Callout>
      </Marker>
    )
  }
}
```